# Why should I type i++; outside the if block?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, max

When finding the max value from an array why should I type `i++` outside the `if` block?

```
int[] x = new int[] { 5, 7, -100, 400, 8 };

int i = 1;
int max;

max = x[0];

while (i < x.Length)
{
    if (x[i] > max)
    {
        max = x[i];
    }
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine("MAX="+max);
```

Comment: Who/What said you should?

Comment: because otherwise you only increment `i` if the value at index i happens to be greater than `max` if it's inside the `if` block. we want to increment it on every iteration.

Comment: This is a classic `for` pattern, i suggest you use it `for(i=1;i < x.Length;i++)`... In fact just us linq `x.Max();`

Comment: Or just replace the whole thing with `Console.WriteLine("MAX="+(new[] { 5, 7, -100, 400, 8 }.Max());`

Comment: Why do you think it should be inside the `if`?

Comment: Truthfully, this is not a coding problem its a logic problem, it has nothing to do with code and more to do with counting and should be closed

Comment: I'm really sorry for this kind of dumb question. (i'm getting so much minus points :D) But i'm new into this so...

Comment: Ignore the negative points. They don't mean anything. If you learnt something new, today was a good day!

Answer (score 4):

If you only incremented `i` *inside* the `if` block, then as soon as the condition `x[i] > max` evaluates to `false`, `i` would not be incremented. And since we're using `i` as the index for the array element to examine, the value of `x[i]` would never change and therefore loop would go on forever.

And, for what it's worth, when you're iterating over an array, a `for` loop is a better fit because it allows you to define the iteration variable, the condition, and the increment all in one place:

```
int[] x = new int[] { 5, 7, -100, 400, 8 };
int max = x[0];

for(int i = 1; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    if (x[i] > max) max = x[i];
}

Console.WriteLine("MAX = " + max);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you i++ inside the if block, you enter to an infinite loop :(

```
        while (i < x.Length)
        {
            if (x[i] > max)
            {
                max = x[i];
                i++;
            }                
        }
```

suppose this array   x = new int[] {9, 8}

```
i = 1
max = 9
while ( 1 < 2 ){//and 1<2 is always true i=1 and x.length=2
     if ( 8 > 9){ //false, never enter
       max = 8
       i++  //never happens, i is always 1
     }    
}
```

---

if you have problems with indexes you can use "foreach", instead of "while"

```
        int[] x = new int[] { 5, 7, -100, 400, 8 };
        int max;

        max = x[0];
        foreach (int elem in x)
        {
            if (elem > max)
                max = elem;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("MAX=" + max);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume if your array consists of following values

```
int[] x = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
```

then how can you find maximum value using `i++` inside the `if` block.You will be stuck in infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

If you put it inside the if block, i will only increment when the max increases, letting the while loop run forever if each value in the array is greater than the one before.

Comment: _if each value in the array is greater than the one before_ That's literally the only time the `while` loop will not be infinite.